# Как оптимизировать import вReact App?

Tags: reactjs, импорт

Есть определенный кусок кода, который хотелось бы оптимизировать ибо выгляди ужасно

````
import Login from "./components/login/login";
import Register from "./components/register/register";
import HomePage from "./components/homePage/homePage";
import  Role  from "./components/helpers/role";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/components/PrivateRouter";
import AdminPage from "./components/adminPage/AdminPage";
import Topics from "./components/homePage/topic";```

Как все эти импорты записать в один файл из которого я смогу брать нужные мне компоненты?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может для кого-то это и выглядит ужасно, но это "нормально". как вариант, создайте файл **myComponents** в который импортируйте все компоненты. внутри файла положите все компоненты в один объект, затем импортируйте этот объект куда хотите, так как компоненты в `React` - это обычные объекты. например:

```
import Login from "./components/login/login";
import Register from "./components/register/register";
import HomePage from "./components/homePage/homePage";
import  Role  from "./components/helpers/role";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/components/PrivateRouter";
import AdminPage from "./components/adminPage/AdminPage";
import Topics from "./components/homePage/topic";

const myComponents = {
  Login,
  Register,
  HomePage,
  Role,
  PrivateRoute,
  AdminPage,
  Topics
}

export default myComponents;
```

затем импортируем:

```
import myComponents from './lala/myComponents';

<myComponents.Login /> // используем
```

но особого преимущества я здест не вижу

Comment: Вопрос:если я импортирую `myComponents` и буду использовать только `Login` как вы указали значит ли это что будет импортироваться все импорты которые   включены?

Comment: @Demon__, конечно. импортируя `myComponents`, Вы импортируете целый объект, который содержит все импорты, а точнее **объект, который просто содержит ссылки на импортируемые компоненты**. ведь в `js` **объект - это просто ссылка на ячейку в памяти**

Comment: Мне понравилось отличная идея так писать.Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @Demon__, пишите как хотите) но этот способ импорта я придумал на ходу, потому что чаще всего все импортируют так, как Вы написали Вашем вопросе. пусть оно и выглядит *некрасиво* и *многословно*, но никого это не смущает. а так, конечно же, импортируйте как душа пожелает. и удачи Вам во `front-end`. с Уважением

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в компонент лежит в отдельной папке, в которой есть index.js, в котором ты делаешь import export этого компонента. 
В итоге у тебя получится

```js
import {component1, component2, component3...} from '../components'
```

Comment: этот `import` для случая, если все компоненты лежат в одном файле `'components'`

Comment: @Август нет, не важно где они лежат, просто из одного файла делается их реэкспорт.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто бе const сразу экспорт